# What are snap loop devices and can I safely remove them?

Tags: partitioning, 17.10, snap

In Ubuntu `17.10` I noticed 2 new partitions when using `gnome-disk-utility`.
From what I understand, they are snap partitions/loop devices created when installing pieces of software. Note that I don't see them listed as partitions in `gparted` which I find confusing.
The problem is I don't know why I have them and would like to get rid of them.

Do I need them? Is it safe to just delete them? For instance, what would happen if I were to delete `bluez_129.snap`, would I lose my Bluetooth tools?

[image: screenshot of 2 loop devices in gnome-disk-utility]

Comment: Also: https://askubuntu.com/q/834093/158442

Comment: Maybe this question could be rephrased as "can I safely remove them?" and after that "if I safely remove them how can I use them again?". Because what's the point of removing a snap loop device if you can't get it back whenever you need to use it?