# Is this a bug in the 'file systems' of 'gnome-system monitor' ? shows so many drives while i have just two

Tags: system-monitor, 18.04

i dont know what a 'squash' is, is this a new feature or a bug? should i report this?

[image]

Comment: "shows so many drives while i have just two" A drive is a device but a device does not have to be a drive.  Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/834093/small-snap-loop-devices-visible-in-gnome-disk-utility-or-what-is-the-function-of