# Post 18.04 upgrade - Massive number of partitions created

Tags: 18.04

Post update :
Login is very slow
Once in the system seems to work OK at normal speed

Looking at System Monitor the number of partitions ( formerly a few in 16.04 )
is now a massively long list, many of which are described as type "squash".

This system has a small SSD for storage - only 40Gb in total.

Obviously I would like to rationalise the mess back down to a few partitions ( as was with 16.04 ) and hopefully resolve the slow bootup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Small snap loop devices visible in gnome-disk-utility OR what is the function of snap ubuntu-core](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834093/small-snap-loop-devices-visible-in-gnome-disk-utility-or-what-is-the-function-of)

Comment: Thank you. That explains why the partitions list looks very different to previous versions of Ubuntu. Many of the lines are for /dev/loop(n) - where n = 0 - 9. These are all? showing 100% utilisation, which would otherwise be rather alarming. The duration of the BOOTUP remains a problem . . . . . 16.04 = 10 seconds approx . . ..  18.04.1 = 60 seconds approx . . . .

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 18.04 comes with many pre-installed snaps (e.g. System Monitor, Calculator etc.) unlike previous releases.

Comment: Will removing any of these snaps a) speed up the bootup : b) cause some other problem ?    $ snap list
core
gnome-3-26-1604
gnome-calculator
gnome-characters
gnome-logs
gnome-system-monitor
gtk-common-themes

Comment: Not sure about a) or whether pre-installed snaps are in fact the reason behind slower bootup. But most likely removing the snaps won't cause any problem, in fact you can replace the applications by their traditional apt version (e.g. `sudo apt install gnome-calculator`).

Comment: I have removed the snaps ( probably the whole snap subsystem ). That solves the mysterious profusion of partitions listed, but the bootup remains very slow. What is the diagnostic process for slow bootup ? Looping in the boot.log ?