# It 's not possible to delete /dev/loop0, Permission denied

Tags: 18.04

How can I delete the `/dev/loop0`,... Until `/dev/loop7` I receive permission denied. On my laptop I have no harddisk. I use only the ram.
I use Ubuntu.

Comment: "I have no harddisk. I use only the ram" What does that have to do anything with presence of these loop devices? You are using snaps regardless. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/834093/small-snap-loop-devices-visible-in-gnome-disk-utility-or-what-is-the-function-of on how to remove them