# I discovered several (about around 100) loop processes in memory of my Xubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop. What are these for and can I safely remove them?

Tags: ram, process, loop-device

loop processes (over 100) in memory:

[image: loop processes (over 100) in memory]

I can see them in taskmanager.

Can anyone tell me what these processes are for, and what uses them? They are all called 
loop (with an increasing number (up to above even 100)). I have more Linux PCs, but of all
4 of them only 1 other has a few loop#
processes (about 8 or so).

I suspect these loop# processes take up 
a lot of my desktop PCs CPU processing power
the system is not really as fast anymore
as when I just installed Xubuntu 18.04.
What can I do to remove these, and is it safe
to do so?

loop processes above 100 in task manager:
[image: loop processes above 100 in task manager]

Comment: Looks like snaps. Been installing any snaps, by chance? Find out with the command `snap list`

Comment: I would suspect the snap sysyem. Try `lsblk` and prepare for a shock.

Comment: right thanks, i see it lsblk shows the snaps installed and its ¨loops¨. i checked this on my other system which has only a few (14) loops. it shows indeed all snaps p7zip/etc. but another question ; are these loops all running in memory like daemons (tsr), or is this only someform of link - what can they do , and what do i have to do about it ? i must say on the system i have 100+ loops, i installed a LOT of apps from linux Software and thus snaps.. _> is this harmful ? can this do any harm to my system (speed/?memory/?) anything ? or do i have to leave it this way

Comment: Related: [Small snap loop devices visible in gnome-disk-utility OR what is the function of snap ubuntu-core](https://askubuntu.com/q/834093/480481)