# Cannot remove /snap directory even after removing snapd

Tags: command-line, snap, storage

I prevously removed `snapd`, however, the `/snap` directory is still there, and consumes a lot of space. How to remove it?

I tried `sudo rm -rf /snap`, but that says

```
rm: cannot remove '/snap/path/to/file': Read-only file system
```

for all files in the directory.

I really did not understand why I could not delete those files even as a superuser, despite `snapd` already being uninstalled.

Comment: I'm not a snap user but it seems `/snap` was mounted as a small loop device which uses squashfs. And squashfs is read-only filesystem. Related to my comment: [Small snap loop devices visible in gnome-disk-utility OR what is the function of snap ubuntu-core](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834093/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it.

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
```

Note: `autoremove` is optional. It removes the dependencies which were explicitly required for `snapd`, and this will free up some space.

Comment: `autoremove` is overkill there, it will remove all packages (not just those pulled by `snapd`) `that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed as dependencies` ([manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt.8.html)). There might be other packages in the OP's system that were automatically installed, no longer needed but still in use. The answer should take care of just the original problem.

Comment: `that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed as dependencies` --- autoremove only removes them only if those other packages are removed. If something is no longer needed, removing that won't break the system. Suppose C is dependency for both A and B. You have uninstalled B. `autoremove` won't remove C unless you manually remove A as well.

Comment: Say you do: `apt-get install lynx snapd`. That will also pull `lynx-common`. Now, remove just `lynx` and your system will still have `lynx-common`, ready to be autoremoved because it is not a dependency anymore. Your command above, at this time, will purge `snapd` **and** remove `lynx-common`. That's quite a side effect for a one-liner meant to take care of just `snapd`.

Comment: Isn't snap required to run Gnome desktop environment on Ubuntu Desktop?

Comment: @ArturMeinild No, you can run Gnome without snap.